# Backbone on Rails how to add a model to a collection from different views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm developing a Rails app using `Rails 3`, and the `backbone-on-rails` gem.

I have a backbone route which shows ProductTypes. It has a backbone view for the list, and a view for the form, so the usar can add new ProductTypes.

Everything works ok, but when I try to add the created model from the form view to the collection on the list view. I don't know how to connect both views.

Here's my route:

```
class Newgvbtool.Routers.ProductTypes extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    'companies/:company_id/product_types': 'index'

  initialize: ->
    @container = $('#product-types-view')
    @company_id = @container.data 'company_id'
    @collection = new Newgvbtool.Collections.ProductTypes([],{ company_id: @company_id })
    @collection.fetch()

  index: (company_id) ->
    view = new Newgvbtool.Views.ProductTypesIndex(collection: @collection)
    @container.append view.render().el

    newModel = new Newgvbtool.Models.ProductType({ company_id: @company_id })
    editView = new  Newgvbtool.Views.ProductTypeEdit model: newModel
    @container.append editView.render().el
```

Her's my model:

```
class Newgvbtool.Models.ProductType extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: (model)-> 
    @company_id = model.company_id
    @id = model.id
  url: ()->
    "/api/companies/#{@company_id}/product_types/" + (@id || '')
```

Here are my views:

```
# Collection view
class Newgvbtool.Views.ProductTypesIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['product_types/index']

  events: ->

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on 'reset', @render
    @collection.on 'add', @appendItem
    @collection.on 'remove', @removeItem

  render: =>
    $(@el).html @template()
    @collection.each @appendItem
    @

  appendItem: (model)=>
    view = new Newgvbtool.Views.ProductType model: model
    $('#product-types tbody').append(view.render().el)

  removeItem: (model)=>
    $('#product-types tbody').find("tr[data-id=#{model.get('id')}]").remove()


 #Item view
 class Newgvbtool.Views.ProductType extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['product_types/product_type']
  tagName: 'tr'

  events:
    'click .delete-item': 'deleteItem'

  initialize: ->
    @model.on 'highlight', @highlight
    @model.on 'change', @render

  render: =>
    $(@el).attr('data-id', @model.get('id')).html @template( model: @model)
    @

  highlight: =>
    @$('td').effect 'highlight', 1000

  deleteItem: ->
    @model.destroy(
      wait: true
    ) if confirm "Are you sure?"

#Form view
class Newgvbtool.Views.ProductTypeEdit extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['product_types/edit']

  render: =>
    $(@el).html @template( model: @model )
    @

  events: ->
    'submit #product-type-form': 'createProductType'

  createProductType: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    attributes = $(e.currentTarget).serializeForm()['product_type']

    @model.save attributes,
      wait: true
      success: (model)->
        $('#product-type-form')[0].reset()
        model.trigger('highlight')
```

Is there a way so when a new model is saved in the form view I can actually add that model to the main collection so the add event is triggered and this new model appears in the collection's view?

And in the case of updating items, can I do the reverse operation, setting the model selected in the list into the form so it can be updated and those changes reflected into the collection's view?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You could give the model a reference to the collection when you initialize it. That way the model could add itself to the collection when the user saves it.

Comment: you could setup a global event "productType:save" and bind your collection to it. Trigger that event on model save. But this is a good strategy if model belongs to multiple collections. I would still prefer that you either do this inside the View where the form event was called. Create Model, Save it, add it to collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you create an event aggregator on your application so you can easily trigger a custom event on a view and a have a listener on another one reacting to it.

Here is a [link](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/) to Derick Bailey post where he explains how this works and gives a couple of ideas of how to implement them.

If you are using a main object to instantiate your application you could do something like this:

```
window.App =
 Models: {}
 Collections: {}
 Views: {}
 Routers: {}

 initialize: ->
  @vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events)
  # More code here

$(document).ready ->
  App.initialize()
```

Then, `App.vent` would be your event aggregator, and you can trigger events like this:

```
App.vent.trigger "model:add:success", @model
```

Here you trigger the "model:add:success" passing the model "@model". Then you can catch it somewhere else with:

```
initialize: ->
  App.vent.on "model:add:success", @appendModel, this
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution!